# Abrir un modal despues de un evento Keypress?

Tags: javascript, modal, bootstrap-4

Hola Programadores estoy trabajando en un proyecto mvc en una entrada electronica para ser mas especifico, estoy intentando validar que si un empleado no esta autorizado para ingresar a un area el sistema genere un modal con el mensaje de ACCESO NO AUTORIZADO adjunto el codigo para ver que estoy haciendo mal:

```
<div class="modal" id="NoAutorizado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">No Autorizado</h5>                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>Acceso no autorizado</h1>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este el codigo que me genera el modal con bootstrap 4

```
<script>
$("#txtGafete").keypress(function (e) {

            if(e.keyCode = 13)
            {
                var gafete = $("#txtGafete").val();
                var mm;                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:49851/api/empleadoAutorizado/" + gafete,
                    method: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",                    
                    success: function (data) {                        
                        if (data == null) {                           
                            denegado();
                        } else {
                            $("#txtNombre").val(data.nombre);                           
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

El modal se deberia ejecutar si el empleado no existe en la base de datos se manifiesta como null, lo llamo con la funccion denegado en la que tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 function denegado()
        {
            $('#NoAutorizado').show();
            setInterval(function () { $('#NoAutorizado').show('hide'), 3000 })                      
        }
```

al ejecutar el proyecto el modal se activa al comenzar a introducir el gafete del empleado y lo que intento es que solo se muestre si el empleado no existe en mi base de datos que puede estar fallando en mi codigo, gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: El `setInterval` no funciona ya que el ultimo paréntesis deber ir antes de `, 3000`, te recomiendo uses `seTimeout` en ves de `setInterval`, intenta con: `setTimeout(function () { $('#NoAutorizado').show('hide') }, 3000 ) `Saludos!!... ;))...

Comment: gracias ya lo implemente y funciona perfectamente gracias por tu respuesta.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cómo estás?

Cambia esto

```
if(e.keyCode === 13){
```

en vez de un solo "=" agrega 2 más para asegurar que sea el tipo de variable correcta, con eso te funcionará.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Jonathan de hecho asi me funciona perfectamente puedo agregar si sabes como hacer para que el modal se cierre de manera automatica despues de 3 segundos lo eh intentado con el setTimeOut pero no me ah funcionado

Comment: Claro, pasa que con un solo "=" por cada tecla que el usuario presione entrará dentro del IF y de ahí es que el modal se dispara.

Si le cambias a "===" solo entrará al if cuando presionen ENTER o INTRO.

Disculpa que no te comenté cual era el error anteriormente, mal yo!

Comment: Agrega tu setTimeout (no setTimeOut) al final del ajax en un .done() como explican en la documentación http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ y me cuentas cómo te fue

Comment: resolvi lo del setTimeOut desarrolle una funcion y luego la llamo desde el evento keyPress y tambien en mi caso en un evento click gracias por tu aporte Jonathan

Comment: Excelente, de esa manera te quedó un código más prolijo y fácil de editar.